# AS3- If Command with two conditions?

Tags: actionscript-3

Right, so I want something to happens when two conditions are met.

Something like:

```
if (11 + 4 == 15 also 13 + 6 == 19){
somethingHappens
}
```

Answer (score 4):

use the [`&&` (logical and) operator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#logical_AND):

```
if (11 + 4 == 15 && 13 + 6 == 19) {
```